# Colorful MDS plot in edgeR

Tags: r, plot, bioinformatics, pca

I have problem to create MDS plot in edgeR to visualize experimental (leukemia) and control (healthy donors) groups in color.

I used htseq files as an input for edgeR. Each file consists of two columns - gene_ID and read counts. "A" stands for leukemia patients, "H" stands for healthy donors.

Here is my code:

Create a table:

```
samples <- matrix(c("A18.txt","experiment","blood_exp",
        "A19.txt","experiment","blood_exp",
        "A20.txt","experiment","blood_exp",
        "A23.txt","experiment","blood_exp",
        "A24.txt","experiment","blood_exp",
        "A26.txt","experiment","blood_exp",
        "A30.txt","experiment","blood_exp",
        "A37.txt","experiment","blood_exp",
        "H11.txt","control","blood_control",
        "H12.txt","control","blood_control",
        "H13.txt","control","blood_control",
        "H15.txt","control","blood_control",
        "H16.txt","control","blood_control",
        "H17.txt","control","blood_control",
        "H18.txt","control","blood_control",
        "H19.txt","control","blood_control"),
    nrow = 16, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c(1:16), c("library_name","condition","group_ALL_vs_control")))

samples <- as.data.frame (samples, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, stringAsFactors = default.stringAsFactors())
```

Use the edgeR function, readDGE, to read in the READS COUNT files created frou htseq-count:

```
counts <- readDGE(samples$library_name, path = 'C:/Users/okbm4/Desktop/htseq_files', columns=c(1,2), group = samples$group_ALL_vs_control, header = FALSE)

colnames(counts) <- samples$library_name
```

Filter weakly expressed and noninformative (i.e.amibigous) features:

```
noint <- rownames(counts) %in% c('__no_feature','__ambiguous','__too_low_aQual','__not_aligned','__alignment_not_unique')

cpms <- cpm(counts)
keep <- rowSums (cpms > 1) >= 4 & !noint
counts <- counts[keep,]
```

Create a DGElist object

```
counts <- DGEList(counts=counts,group = samples$group_ALL_vs_control)
```

Estimate normalization factor, this is the normalization for the library size

```
counts <- calcNormFactors(counts)
```

Inspect relationships between samples using MDS plot.

```
pdf(file = 'HCB_ALL.pdf', width = 9, height = 6)

plotMDS(counts, labels = c('A18.txt','A19.txt','A20.txt','A23.txt','A24.txt','A26.txt','A30.txt','A37.txt','H11.txt','H12.txt','H13.txt','H15.txt','H16.txt','H17.txt','H18.txt','H19.txt'), 

xlab = 'Dimension 1',
ylab = 'Dimension 2', 
asp = 6/9,
cex = 0.8,

main = 'Multidimentional scaling plot')
par(cex.axis =0.6, cex.lab = 0.6, cex.main = 1)
```

I attached file that I generate before.
[image]

I would be glad to hear any suggestions.

Comment: Please consider if all this code is really necessary to demonstrate what you're trying to achieve (color some points).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plotMDS()` produces an object that can be passed to `plot()` just as it
is,
so that you can choose your own plotting symbols and x and y axis
labels:

```
 mds <- plotMDS(yourdata)
   plot(mds)
```

You can add any arguments to `plot()` to choose plotting symbols, colors
etc.